# uitextfield selected changes status bar color

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uistatusbar

I can't find what is wrong with `UITextField` (or `UIStatusBar`).

In my

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I have:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Also in my view controller I have this:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

The color of `UIStatusBar` is always white as I want it to be. But whenever I select `UITextField`, it's color changes to black. I don't want that, and I always want it to be white.

Strange but I can't find any similar issues on the net, so I'm hoping for your help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want the `UIStatusBar` with `whiteColor` insert the line like you did in `didFinishLaunching`

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
   setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

and than also set a value for the statusbar inside info.plist like this

[image]

You just need to set `preferredStatusBarStyle` inside a `UIViewController` if you want to change the color for a single controller.

Comment: This is helpful, but what if I need a statusbar color depending on controller, I just don't need the color to change on when I select the textfield..?

Comment: Did you already change the property inside the info.plist? I also inserted a `UITextField` and tried it to but the `UIStatusBar` color is still white when selecting the textfield. Maybe you have any actions which trigger `prefferedStatusBarStyle` or you change the bar anywhere else in the code.

Comment: no I don't. Your suggested solution works, unless I need a View controller-based status bar. Thanks for the help though. It works for now

Answer (score 0):

Just Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to **YES** in the plist file
and also put in `viewDidLoad` method `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` may be its work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but that also doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to YES in the plist

In viewDidLoad do a [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

Add the following method:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
  return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```

Comment: I don't need to hide it, I need it's text to be always white

Comment: I am doing this already, but it still changes color to black if i select a uitextfield.

Comment: set the preferredsattusbarstyle to NO and in appDelegate inside appDidFinishLaunching method, put [[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]

Answer (score 0):

Okay this must not happen and so i don't see a need of setting the UIStatusBarStyle again and again... could you give a little more information about your UITextField?

Comment: It's a simple/standard UITextField. When I select it my status bar color changes. Never seen this before though.

Comment: yeah same here... never heard of any such thing myself!!! anyway are you doing anything in any delegate function for the textfield??

Comment: no I am not doing anything. If I'm doing as 亚历山大 suggested, then it doesn't change. But if I would like dynamic uistatusbar color depending on controller which I will need later then I need a different solution.

Comment: okay i don't really know why but i just noticed that on touching the textfield the preferredStatusBarStyle gets called again...